Execution of "...\sandbox.sys" failed Code::Blocks
Recently, I was trying to make very simple program in C about calculating rectangle area and perimeters for my students on Code::Blocks.
I am getting that done by header files and implementation files gather program functions.
The problem is when I was testing accessing header file by a path the whole project got corrupted it doesn't build because some execution failures.
Picture when I try to build and run:

Picture of current .c and .h files location:

I tried to put the files back to the project directory and including the file as normal but the problem is still there.

Please don't tag languages you're not using. I don't think .sys is a valid executable extension, it's usually used for drivers

Did you select a correct project type?
